# Database not selected

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Please can someone help me figure out what's going in my code? I want to get username and password from my database since I have not created a registration page and it's saying no database selected.

```
DB_NAME= laundry_login
TABLE= users
USERNAME= peace
PASSWORD= ********
```

Please help me check and make corrections

```
<?php
    function SignIn()
    {
        session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
        if(!empty($_POST['username']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
        {
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM laundry_login WHERE username= '$_POST[username]' AND hashed_password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
            if(!empty($row['username']) AND !empty($row['hashed_password']))
            {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['hashed_password'];
                echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO LAUNDRY PAGE...";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERED WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['laund'])) //where laund is the name for my submit button
    {
        SignIn();
    }
?>
```

Comment: are you at least connected? the Q is confusing. Show the other code in this stuff, such as the connect, the db_change, that uses this deprecated mysql_* library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql_select_db function for select the database.

Answer (score 1):

After connection with the database, you should have a code like

```
mysql_select_db('laundry_login');
```

And you mysql query should be

```
mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM users WHERE username= '$_POST[username]' AND hashed_password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

At database connection, you should be like this.

```
<?php 
    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "peace";
    $password = "********";
    $db = "laundry_login";

    $conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    $selected = mysql_select_db($db,$conn); 
?>
```

This piece of code could be separate file or in your sign-in file before query.If you saved with separate file named "***db_config.php***" in same directory of your sign-in file, it could be loaded with require function at the start of your document. Like this below,

```
<?php
    require("db_config.php"); // loading db_config.php

    function SignIn()
    {

    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you all, i got it up and running.